# Postgres truncate the millisecond part from three to two digits

Tags: postgresql

I am formatting an input that I get in Timestamp datatype and sending the output as a text in the below format

`2020-07-30 10:45:23.638 PM`

For this I'm using the below query

`select to_char(input_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MS AM');`

But I want the microsecond part truncated to 2 digits instead of 3 digits. The output will be in TEXT datatype. Expecting help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    left(to_char(input_timestamp::timestamp(2), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MS'), 22) || 
    to_char(input_timestamp, 'FM AM');
```

First round to two microsecond' digits, convert to string, chop to 22 characters and then concatenate the meridiem indicator.